# NMaxValue - function is not a real number

Tags: mathematical-optimization, numerical-value, maximum

I'm trying to use `NMaxValue` to numerically find maximal values of the function `F[z]`. The problematic part of my code is as follows:

```
p = 2/3;

λ[t_] := Exp[-t];
H2[x_] := -x Log2[x] - (1 - x) Log2[1 - x];
hp[z_] := (1 + z)/4 (1 - λ[t]^2) (1 - p);
hm[z_] := (1 - z)/4 (1 - λ[t]^2) (1 - p);
Δp[z_] := 
  1/4 (1 + λ[t]^2 + z*p (1 - λ[t]^2) + Sqrt[4 (λ[t]^2 + 
          z*p (1 - λ[t]^2)) + (1 - λ[t]^2)^2 (p + z)^2]);
Δm[z_] := 
  1/4 (1 + λ[t]^2 + z*p (1 - λ[t]^2) + Sqrt[4 (λ[t]^2 + z*p (1 - λ[t]^2)) + (1 - λ[t]^2)^2 (p - z)^2]);

F[z_] := H2[(1 + z)/2] + H2[(1 + p + λ[t]^2 (1 - p))/2] - hp[z] Log2[hp[z]] - 
   hm[z] Log2[hm[z]] - Δp[z] Log2[Δp[z]] - Δm [z] Log2[Δm[z]];

t = 61/100;

CE = NMaximize[{F[z], -1 <= z <= 1}, z];
```

When calculating CE, Mathematica returns:

> "NMaximize::nrnum: The function value -2.36092-0.101127 I is not a
> real number at {z} = {-0.868794}.".

How do I force maximization over real `F[z]` only?

Comment: `NMaximize[Re@F[z], -1 <= z <= 1, z]`

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to maximize over the real part of the function, not over real functions...

Comment: When all of the variables are real and all of the intermediate results are real, `F[z]` just equal to `Re@F[z]`.

Answer (score 6):

If you plot your function F[z]

```
Plot[F[z], {z, -0.7, 1}]
```

you can see that the max is somewhere near -0.25. Since your function becomes complex valued at around -0.6, you need to restrict the search. Hence

```
NMaximize[{F[z], -0.6 < z < 1}, z]

{2.91233, {z -> -0.225441}}
```

gives the max value.

Comment: Thank you! I've tried NMaximize, too, but it behaved just like NMaxValue. It's so strange that limiting the range of the variable fixes the problem!

Comment: The solver is expecting to see real numbers since it doesn't mean anything to try and "maximize" a complex number. Another way to fix the problem is to use NMaximize[{Abs[F[z]], -1 <= z <= 1}, z]. This returns the same result.

Answer (score 2):

With your function definitions,

```
t = 61/100;
```

For your interval of interest (`-1 <= z <= 1`), the function `F[z]` is real when

```
fd = FunctionDomain[{F[z], -1 <= z <= 1}, z] // Simplify

(* 3 E^(61/50) (2 + z) >= 2 + 2 E^(61/100) Sqrt[-13 + 8 E^(61/50)] + 
  3 z && z < 1 *)
```

or approximately

```
fd // N // Simplify

(* -0.628735 <= z < 1. *)
```

The maximum is

```
CE = NMaximize[{F[z], fd}, z]

(* {2.91233, {z -> -0.225441}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot. I'll definitely implement FunctionDomain into my code.